# Pull a variable and its location in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to cycle through the variables of an array I've created to pull the 'winner' to a new array.
I can bring the score over but then lose the position of where it was in the array.

Basically, I want it to do this:

```
players = [23,41,15,65,18]
Player 4 has won( with a score of 65)
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

To find the maximum element in an array. (and as such the max score)

```
int max = 0;
int player = 0;
for (int i=0; i<players.length; i++){
   if (players[i] > max){
       player = i+1;
       max = players[i]
   }
}
System.out.println("Player "+player+" has won( with a score of "+max+")");
```

I hope this helps.

Edit: As someone pointed out the player (if counting the first as 1) would be i+1. Thanks.

Comment: Rather `player = i + 1;`  The player where `i == 0` is player 1; the player where `i == 3` is player 4; you get the idea.